# Custom etag generation

Tags: apache2, nginx

How can I configure an apache or nginx server to send Etag headers using an algorithm of my choosing (i.e. not involving inode, mtime or size)? Is there any alternative to compiling a new C module?

Comment: Do you have a use case when you need to set own `ETag` for static files?

Comment: Served from a cluster - inode and mtime won't be same for same versions, size may be same for different versions

Comment: Nginx has built-in Perl, this seems a good job for it. It works very well (reliable and fast) in situations when you have no lock on remote resource (e.g. database).

Answer (score 5):

In Apache, [ETags are handled as a core feature](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#fileetag). The ETag is computed as a hash of several values. You can use the `FileETag` directive in your `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` file to define conditional behavior for which values to include in the hash, but as you pointed out, your options are limited to:

- `INode` - your file's i-node number on the particular server it's served from
- `MTime` - the timestamp (in millis) of the server your file is served from
- `Size` - the size of your file in bytes
- `All` - all of the above
- `None` - none of the above

If you want truly custom ETag generation, you would definitely be best off writing an Apache module. However if you need a quick-and-dirty fix, you can generate your own tags by routing your requests to a PHP script and appending the `Etag` header in the script. The route might look like this in your `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.png$     # This example looks for .png requests
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gentag.php?path=$1 [B] # ...and routes them to a PHP script
```

The PHP script might look like this:

```
<?
    $path = $_GET['path'];  // Grab the filepath from GET params
    $cont = file_get_contents($path);  // Get file contents to hash
    $hash = crc32($cont);   // Create your own ETag hash however you like
    header("Etag: $hash");  // Send the custom Etag header
    echo $cont;             // Dump the file contents to output
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some comments in [this](https://github.com/apache/httpd/pull/13) PR that could address what your looking for. It isn't an algorithm of your choosing, but it is MD5, which is pretty solid.

You'll note that they present two options.

1. Use the modified date of the file, but have a build process artificially mutate the modified date of the file based on a hash of the file. Then this modified date can be included in the `ETag` header calculation (don't use it as the `Last-Modified` header, as it may be in the future).
2. Use the [Content Digest](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#contentdigest) feature of Apache to get an MD5 hash of the file as a header. You can then manipulate that as needed.